# Trying to add column to dataGridView1 but getting exception InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, winforms

dataGridView1 is added in the designer.
And in the designer i added 9 columns.

Then in the constructor in form1 i did:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn());
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);
DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell)dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1];
```

Then in the Form1 Load event i did:

```
_thisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
InitializeRefreshTimer();
PopulateApplications();
```

Then the timer init method:

```
void InitializeRefreshTimer()
        {
            _refreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            _refreshTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
            _refreshTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerToUpdate_Elapsed);    
            _refreshTimer.Start();
        }
```

Then the timer elapsed event:

```
void TimerToUpdate_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateApplications();
        }
```

Then the PopulateApplications method:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();            
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p.MainWindowTitle, status);
                    cell.Value = ima;
                }
            }
        }
```

What i want to do is to add to the first column in dataGridView1 all the icons for each process in the cell under the first column. And the icons should be display only in the first column cells icon of each process.

I tested it i saved the variable ima to the hard disk and i saw the icons there as Images. 
But i can't find the way to add the icons(Images) to the dataGridView1.

And also i'm getting exception on the line:

```
DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell)dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1];
```

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageCell'.

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageCell'.
  Source=HardwareMonitoring
  StackTrace:
       at HardwareMonitoring.Form1..ctor() in Form1.cs:line 132
       at HardwareMonitoring.Program.Main() inProgram.cs:line 17
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Please show where you instantiate `dataGridView1` and add any other columns to it.

Comment: STLD dataGridView1 is added in the designer. I will update my question with the full code.

Comment: Do you add any other columns?  Does the grid view start out with one column by default?

Comment: STLD updated my question. I have 9 columns already in the designer and i also explained what is my main goal to add the icons of each process on the first column cells. Only on the first column cells. But i didn't find yet how to add this icons. So i tried this line in the constructor but it give exception.

Comment: The reason for the failure is this: You add a new `DataGridViewImageColumn` to the existing set of 9 columns, giving you 10 columns, but you're trying to cast a cell in the 2nd column ([1]), which is for text, to type image, which it clearly is not, thus causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the column type is not set right:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell'`

When you add new columns to your `DataGridView` the default selected type is `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, which results in `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`-type cells. Edit the columns in the designer and try switching the `ColumnType` to `DataGridViewImageColumn`. Your current cells are only for text.

Comment: Ashton so i changed now both to 0 Rows[0] and Cells[0] and i must say again i already have 9 columns i added in the designer before. And after changed both from 1 to 0 stil same exception.

Comment: I updated the whole answer as the problem was not the indexes.